# Compiz/Unity broken with ATI Radeon HD6670 Ubuntu 13.04 after reboot

Tags: drivers, 13.04, compiz, radeon, fglrx

I have had my display working correctly on a new machine (Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit, ATI Radeon HD6670) for the last 3 weeks using the proprietary driver downloaded from the ATI website. Yesterday, I rebooted the machine and now Compiz is broken. I have no Unity menu, no sidebars, no window decoration. I have tried following the instructions:

[Compiz has broken after installing 12.10 with ATI Catalyst 12.10 drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206228/compiz-has-broken-after-installing-12-10-with-ati-catalyst-12-10-drivers)

to completely remove the driver, rebuild the .deb packages and reinstall. However I still have no compiz etc. fglrxinfo gives:

```
    sudo fglrxinfo
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6670
OpenGL version string: 4.2.12217 Compatibility Profile Context 12.104
```

actually ps aux|grep compiz indicates that compiz is actually running, but I have no effects (e.g. prior to the reboot I had "wobbly windows" effect), no window decoration & no Unity launcher.

Thanks.

When I start gnome-panel from a terminal, it starts but gives:

```
(gnome-panel:5308): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_accelerator_parse_with_keycode: assertion `accelerator != NULL' failed

** (gnome-panel:5308): WARNING **: Unable to parse mouse modifier '(null)'
```

Windows can't be moved or resized

Comment: I think I have pinned this down to something in my profile. If I create a new user & log in as them, the display works fine. Any suggestions appreciated on which files I need to copy across from the other user to correct my display problem.

Comment: Could be something wrong with xorg.conf. After removing proprietary driver did you do `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf` then a reboot?

Comment: Hi Chris, yes I did remove xorg.conf, however, it turns out to be a compiz config issue. I resolved this by starting compiz settings manager, going to "preferences" and "Reset to Defaults". All ok now. Cheers, Alan

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, you can provide and accept your own answer. It may help others in the future.

Comment: Yep will do, it won't let me for another 4 hours though for some reason

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by starting compiz settings manager (sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager), going to "preferences" and "Reset to Defaults".